# Extract data from http call node js

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase

Hey guys I am trying to pull some data from a http request in a firebase pub sub function. Here is my current function I have ommited my api key

```
async function requestPromise(path: string) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
        hostname: "pro-api.coinmarketcap.com",
        path: "/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=10&convert=USD",
        method:"GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization: "Omitted",
        },
    };

    http.get(options, (resp) => {
        let data = "";

        resp.on("data", (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        resp.on("end", () => {
            resolve(data);
        });

    }).on("error", (error) => {
        reject(error);
    });
});
```

}

```
 exports.updateCoinPrices = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 5 minutes")
.onRun(async (context) => {

    await (async function () {
        try {
            await requestPromise("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=query=limit=").then((data) => {
                console.log("the data is")
                console.log(data)
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
    return null;
});
```

Here is what I get from firebase data is
and here is what the data should be coming in as any ideas ?

[image: json]

Comment: This one `await (async function () {}` wrap looks strange to me. While `data.data` is an array and `data.status` is an object. I mean, what's the question?

Comment: when i try to print data to the console though I get nothing, do it should be data.data ? sorry I never use js/ts I much prefer kotlin but you cant use kotlin on cloud functions as far as im aware.